# Launch a folder in linux?

Tags: linux

I know i can launch a folder in windows by using

```
explorer.exe path
```

How do i do the same in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On GNOME systems use:

```
gnome-open /dir/name
```

On KDE systems use:

```
kde-open /dir/name
```

Actually the commands would open anything you throw at them using associated application.

I'm surprised that apparently neither [FreeDesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/) nor [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) standardized that yet.

Comment: F yes. This is a great solution. This is the only one which worked for me.

Comment: note, by doing this i saw mention of xdg-open which has been mentioned by FreeDesktop. My code does this first and checks the return code. If not 0 it will attempt with gnome (what i am using) then KDE

Answer (score 7):

"Linux" doesn´t say much, but

If you are using gnome, and nautilus.

```
$nautilus path
```

For example

```
$nautilus /home/jimmy/jimmys_files
```

If you are using KDE, try

```
$konqueror path
```

Comment: Or `$dolphin path`. Konqueror needs to be configured to use the Dolphin KPart for it to open folders, but it usually is by default.

Comment: or `$thunar path` if using XFCE.

Comment: What's the deal with the $ sigils?  It seems pretty unlikely that those apps wouldn't be in the path.  It would be more clear to just take them out, so as not to confuse people who don't understand that `$nautilus` means "the `nautilus` executable, wherever it happens to be on your system".  In the context of this question, I don't think we're expecting people to be writing shell scripts that need to run without a standard `$PATH` set.

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you're using KDE, it's either:

```
dolphin /path/to/folder
```

or:

```
konqueror /path/to/folder
```

depending on which you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Well... all the answers are good but no one will open it in explorer! :)
If you have wine installed and you probably have, this one will! :) (a rather oldish version but... explorer!)

```
wine explorer c:\\users\\youruser
```

OBS: I think this is not what you want to do and it's useless but I couldn't resist!

Answer (score 2):

Just type:

```
nautilus /path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know i can launch a folder in windows by using

No, you can open a folder in Windows explorer by doing that

> How do i do the same in linux?

What file manager do you want to use? In most cases it will be the same syntax, but with the name of the file manager you are actually using.

Comment: "No, you can open a folder in Windows explorer by doing that" <-- i never used a version of windows where i couldnt

Comment: "where you couldn't" open a folder in Windows explorer by doing that. The point is, you're not "launching a folder in Windows," you're opening it in Explorer. And the Linux equivalent of that action depends on what file manager you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
gksudo nautilus path/to/directory
```

to run a nautilus window as root.

Answer (score 0):

nautilus ~ for your home and nautilus / for opening the root. For other windoyish shortcuts in Ubuntu please refer http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9636969